# PHP echo - How to make a button not appear when no URL entered in mySQL?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I want the Sign In Button to only appear on a site when a URL is entered. As is, it appears with or without URL.

```
<a class='button' href='<?php echo $expert['url'];?>'>Sign in</a>
```

I tried different ways, nothing works.

```
<?php if($url==1){?>
<a class='button' href='<?php echo $expert['url'];?>'>Sign in</a>
<?php }?>
```

What am I missing?

It seems like such as simple fix!

Comment: Where is `$expert['url']` defined?

Comment: And where is `$url` defined?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. It is in mySQL. <a class='button' href='<?php echo $expert['url'];?>'>Sign in</a> This alone works. The problem is that if I do not enter a URL (which sometimes I do not need to), it shows me the text Sign In.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (empty($expert['url'])) {
echo "No URL";
 } else {
echo "<a class='button' href='$expert['url']'>Sign in</a>";
}
?>
```

I think what you need to use is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: I tried it and it gives me error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/content/d/o/r/dornhosting/html/thermasource/index.php on line 2017"

Comment: Can you explain where is $expert['url'] defined?

Comment: It defines a field in my CMS where I can enter a URL if I want too. It is not a required field. The CMS is based on mySQL.

Comment: OK, I'll change my answer test it.

Comment: Sorry. Did you change your answer? I am not sure. :-)

Comment: I tried, same error on page. I also tried with elseif ($is_url==0), same thing.

Comment: Test this echo $expert['url'];  and see what's the output.

Comment: <?php  $exper=mysql_query("select * from expertise where status='0' order by order_id");
$e=1;    while($expert=mysql_fetch_assoc($exper))
{
?>
<div class='col-sm-4' style='<?php if($e==2){?>margin-left:725px !important;margin-top:-10px !important;<?php }?>'>
<p class="text-left"><img class="button" alt="" width="340" height="188" src="IMPORT/<?php echo $expert['image'];?>" /></p>
<h3 class='title'><a href="#"><?php echo $expert['heading'];?></a></h3>
<?php echo $expert['text'];?> 
<a class='button' href='<?php echo $expert['url'];?>'>Sign in</a>

Comment: Sorry. it looks messy but my code works. I just want to add some PHP to tell the "Sign In" anchor to not show up if there is no URL. Does it make sense?

Comment: This answer should work for you. Probably there is a missing bracket or something when implemented. Can you point to where line 2017 is in your code?

Comment: OK, now I understand what do you need, test my new answer.

Comment: Change the code `<a class='button' href='<?php echo $expert['url'];?>'>Sign in</a>` exactly with `<?php if ($expert['url']):?><a class='button' href='<?php echo $expert['url'];?>'>Sign in</a><?php endif; ?>` (there is no need to check for isset() as the field is set even if its empty in the db)

Comment: Check mark my answer as true, or by click on up button.